# Angular 2+ Unit testing a service that calls a service that calls an httpclient get

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, typescript

I have found many examples online on how to test a service that makes an API request, but for a service that:

- calls another service which makes an HTTP request and passes this
  back to the original service
- makes an http request based on that

I am struggling to get it to work. Here's an example of my code:

```
beforeEach((done) => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            RouterTestingModule,
            HttpClientTestingModule,
            JwtModule.forRoot({
                jwtOptionsProvider: {
                    provide: JWT_OPTIONS,
                    useFactory: jwtOptionsFactory,
                    deps: []
                }
            }),
        ],
        providers: [
            ConfigService,
            AuthenticationService,
            UserService,
            JobService
        ]
    });

    let injector = getTestBed();
    sut = injector.get(JobService);
    httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);
});

describe('Appointment Management', () =>{
    it('should set an apointment', () => {
        expect(sut).toBeDefined();
        const dummyResponse = 'dsfsdf';

        sut
        .setAppointmentDate('temp', new Date(2017, 12, 31))
        .subscribe(result => {
            expect(result).toEqual(dummyResponse)
        })

        const req = httpMock.expectOne('http://localhost:32307/appointments');
        expect(req.request.method).toBe('POST');
        req.flush(dummyResponse);
    });
})
```

For extra clarity of what is going on here, jobservice is under test. It has dependencies of configService and userService.

user service has dependencies of configService and authentication service.

router and jwt service are dependencies of authentication service and user service.

all services also depend on httpclient.

THE ACTUAL RESPONSE I AM GETTING:

> Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

it shouldn't even be making a real call so I am unsure why it times out. I have tried stubbing out the calls the dependencies make as well and that resulted in the same error eg

```
const userRequest = httpMock.expectOne('http://localhost:32307/user');
userRequest.flush('temp');
```

Comment: @mplungjan I wasn't the one who downvoted, but the question doesn't contain the code that is being tested and lacks http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: the only way I could see it being clearer is if I wrapped the whole thing in the top level describe - which I didnt see in any point in. But I have never been able to get a question on here that wasnt downvoted :D

Comment: Would be useful to tell OP and the rest of us the reason for voting down.

Comment: @Craig Please, provide all relevant code. The services you're testing. They are not there. Otherwise the question cannot gain a quality answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you unit testing, you test **what the service being tested does**. You don't test what its dependencies do.

This means, you only have to test if the service is calling the other service, and mock the return.

Since jobService is under test, and calls config & user services (from what you wrote that I understood), you should test your function like so :

```
US = injector.get(UserService);
CS = injector.get(ConfigService);

it('Testing a function called myFunc in your service ...', () => {
  spyOn(US, 'myUserServiceFunctionCalled')
    .and.returnValue(Observable.of('The mocked answer returned by this function'))
  spyOn(CS, 'myConfigServiceFunctionCalled')
    .and.returnValue(Observable.of('The mocked answer returned by this function'))

  sut.myFunc(); // .subscribe if it's an Observable, and put your expects in it
  expect(US.myUserServiceFunctionCalled).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(CS.myConfigServiceFunctionCalled).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: This looks very much like what I need. I am still getting the same error but thanks for getting me on the right track!

Comment: No problem ! Unmock your HTTP calls if you don't need them anymore, maybe this could eras your issue !

Comment: (and by unmock, I mean delete)

Comment: I have marked this as it was very helpful but for anyone else that runs into this problem I solved this by setting up the spies shown above in the beforeEach to return some stubbed responses.

I am still using the flush method to mock my service under test http response and I solved the async callback timeout error by giving the beforeEach a 'done' callback which I call after setting up all my spies and injector mocks. I guess setting up the testbed caused issues because the provided services have constructors that use their dependencies http methods so it was not finishing before my test.

Comment: I hope this helps people!

Comment: Thank you, but to add to this statement, you should only add the spies in the `beforeEach` if the functions called are called in every test ! otherwise, that's time and resources wasted : sure it doesn't matter on a little project, but in a huge one, it's not a good practice !